# Alternate solution to After Effects rendering with Caps Lock on

Tags: adobe, rendering, after-effects

> Press Caps Lock to prevent After
>   Effects from updating Footage, Layer,
>   or Composition panels. When you make a
>   change that would otherwise appear in
>   a panel, After Effects adds a red bar
>   with a text reminder at the bottom of
>   the panel. After Effects continues to
>   update panel controls such as motion
>   paths, anchor points, and mask
>   outlines as you move them. To resume
>   panel updates and display all changes,
>   press Caps Lock again.
>   http://help.adobe.com/en_US/aftereffects/cs/using/WSF13D6BED-C53B-408a-B2D6-C8B4205D4FB7a.html

Is there a way to get the same effect of the above without using Caps Lock? Maybe there is a way to enable a setting to render without updating Footage, Layer, or Composition panels without using the Caps Lock hot key?

Comment: I have searched for an answer to this but I think Caps Lock is the only way.  I am mostly annoyed when I want to type all caps text and when I change my selection away from the text field, my preview render goes blank.